# How to create image from binary string

Tags: python, image, rsa

I read binary from file image, each 128-bytes and encrypt using rsa. but after encrypt i can't create image from binary. I created funtion genarate key rsa. I convert binary to int for encrypt

```
from PIL import Image
import KeyRSA
import RsaMath

pub, piv = KeyRSA.GenerateRsaKey(size=1024)
n, e = pub

with open("hinh.png", "rb") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
step = 128
cipher_data = []
for i in range(0, len(data), step):
    value = data[i:i+step]
    m = RsaMath.OS2IP(value)
    c = pow(m, e, n)
    cipher_data.append(RsaMath.I2OSP(c, 128))

cipher_data = "".join(cipher_data)

im = Image.open("hinh.png")
W, H = im.size
img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (W,H), cipher_data)
img.show()e here
```

Comment: Where are `KeyRSA` and `RsaMath` from? Your problem is because you're encrypting the bytes of the PNG file, not the raw pixel data. But it's hard to give a more specific answer without knowing what the `KeyRSA` and `RsaMath` module functions do.

Comment: Hi. KeyRSA just generate key for RSA. RsaMath contain IO2SP and O2ISP funtion to con vert octet string to number and number to octet string.

Comment: So use PIL to open the source image and use the image [`.tobytes`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes) method to get the raw pixel byte data. If its an RGB image of size WxH you will get 3*W*H bytes. I assume your RSA encoding algorithm outputs the same number of bytes that you feed it if you only feed it whole 128 byte blocks.

Comment: So. when i encrypted. i wanted to create image from byte. how to do it. sorry i bad

Comment: `img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (W,H), cipher_data)` will work if `cipher_data` contains _exactly_ 3*W*H bytes. The resulting image of the RSA-encrypted data will just be random-looking noise, but I assume that's what you want.

Comment: FWIW, if I had access to `KeyRSA` and `RsaMath` I would have written you a complete working program in an answer, but I don't like to write code that I cannot test.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have access to KeyRSA and RsaMath I decided to use the [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) package. Raw RSA encryption is *not* safe, and it's slow, so instead this code uses AES, which is fast, and quite safe to use in block mode with 128 byte blocks.

Rather than reading an image from a file, the code below generates a simple two color image. It then encrypts it, converts the encrypted data to an image, which it displays and saves as a PNG. It then decrypts the encrypted data to recover the original image.

The encryption process is performed using 128 byte chunks, so you can easily adapt it to your RSA encryption algorithm, if you *really* want to do that. However, it's more efficient to perform the encryption in one step; I've included a commented-out line that shows how to do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Create a simple image and encrypt it with AES

    See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44314026/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2017.06.02
'''

from PIL import Image
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def color_square(size, colors):
    ''' Make a square that fades diagonally
        from the 1st color to the 2nd color
    '''
    m = 255.0 / (2 * size - 2)
    r = range(size)
    mask = bytes(int(m * (x + y)) for y in r for x in r)
    mask = Image.frombytes('L', (size, size), mask)
    imgs = [Image.new('RGB', (size, size), color=c) for c in colors]
    return Image.composite(imgs[0], imgs[1], mask)

# Create a simple image
size = 128
img = color_square(size, ('red', 'blue'))
img.show()

# Extract the raw pixel data from the image
src_data = img.tobytes()
print('Original length:', len(src_data), size*size*3)

# Create an AES cipher object
key = b'This is a key123'
iv = b'This is an IV456'
crypto = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

# Encrypt the data in 128 byte chunks
blocks = []
for i in range(0, len(src_data), 128):
    blocks.append(crypto.encrypt(src_data[i:i+128]))
cipher_data = b''.join(blocks)

# We could actually encrypt it in one step with
#cipher_data = crypto.encrypt(src_data)
print('Encoded length', len(cipher_data))

# Convert the encrypted data to an image & display it
img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (size, size), cipher_data)
img.show()
img.save('redblue_AES.png')

# We need a fresh AES cipher object to do the decoding
crypto = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decoded_data = crypto.decrypt(cipher_data)
print('Decoded length', len(decoded_data))

# Convert the decrypted data to an image & display it
img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (size, size), decoded_data)
img.show()
img.save('redblue.png')
```

Here are redblue.png and redblue_AES.png

[image: redblue.png - the recovered original]
[image: redblue_AES.png - the encrypted version]

Comment: why when decrypt you not read image encrypted. when i read image encrypted to decrypt. it not work :(

Comment: @mr.hiep I didn't bother reading the bytes from the encrypted image because I already have them in `cipher_data`. But if you want to extract the bytes from the encrypted image just do `cipher_data = img.tobytes()`, which is the same thing we did to extract the bytes from the original image.

Comment: look my answer. please tell me why?

Comment: @mr.hiep please edit any clarification into your question and not by posting an answer. Please bear in mind that the author of this post has already solved your original question. Please stop commenting at them requesting additional help. If you have a new question, then spend time formulating a good question and ask it as a new question. Thank you.

Comment: @mr.hiep Your answer isn't an answer, it's a new question. If you want to ask it in a new question you need to include some test data that doesn't decrypt correctly so people can reproduce the problem.