# Need help to encrypt/decrypt images

Tags: python, image, encryption, rsa, python-imaging-library

I am using RSA to encrypt an image and Pillow to read it byte by byte. I am encrypting each 128-bytes. But when I try to decrypt it back, the resulting image it is not like the original. 
Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from PIL import Image


def genearteRSAKeys(keyLength):
    private = RSA.generate(keyLength)
    public = private.publickey()
    privateKey = private.exportKey()
    publicKey = public.exportKey()
    return privateKey, publicKey


def rsaEncrypt(pubKey, data):
    publicKey = RSA.importKey(pubKey)
    encryptData = publicKey.encrypt(data, "")
    return encryptData

def rsaDecrypt(pivKey, data):
    privateKey = RSA.importKey(pivKey)
    decryptData = privateKey.decrypt(data)
    return decryptData


im = Image.open("photo.jpg")
w, h = im.size
data = im.tobytes()

privateKey, publicKey = genearteRSAKeys(1024)

step = 128
block_cipher = []
for i in range(0, len(data), step):
    encrypted = rsaEncrypt(publicKey, data[i:i+step])
    block_cipher.append(''.join(encrypted))

data_cipher = ''.join(block_cipher)

img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (w, h), data_cipher)
img.save("photo2.jpg")

image = Image.open("photo2.jpg")
data_encrypt = image.tobytes()
block_plant =[]
for j in range(0, len(data_encrypt), step):
    decrypted = rsaDecrypt(privateKey, data_encrypt[j:j+step])
    block_plant.append(''.join(decrypted))

data_plant = ''.join(block_plant)

image2 = Image.frombytes("RGB", (w,h), data_plant)
image2.show()
```

why isn't this code working?

Comment: could anyone explain me why this question has been downvoted so hard? I don't get it

Comment: @BPL Because you do not give a lot of explanation about the expected behaviour, and it looks like you just want us to correct your code, without trying to do it by yourself. Note that I said "it **looks like**".

Comment: Can you link the pictures (before, after encryption/decryption) ?

Comment: This is a follow-on question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314026/how-to-create-image-from-binary-string

Comment: @Rightleg First of all, it's not my question... but if you take your time to read it, the question looks correct. In fact, if you research a little bit you'll see the guy is using pycrypto package and he's put the effort to use that package and wondering why the results are not the ones he's expecting. I mean, you'll see thousands of really really lazy questions all around this website being upvoted and some decent ones like the above ones where people can learn some useful stuff being downvoted. No, it's not right

Comment: The low-level RSA routines from pycrypto are _not_ designed to handle arbitrary raw bytes. They are designed to be called by higher level routines that pass them data which has been properly prepared and padded. The core RSA encryption calculation is `c = pow(m, e, n)`. That won't give the correct result if `m >= n`. Instead it'll give you `pow(m%n, e, n)`.

Comment: @BPL Fair enough, I thought it was OP who was commenting. Well, I refrained myself from voting, because the question is not obviously bad, nor is it obviously good, and I don't know that topic to judge it by myself. Still, no precise expected behaviour is included, not even the said image to visualize and reproduce the problem. So I do think it **looks like** a "correct my code" question, which **I assume** brought people to think this was a poor question. It might be a good and interesting one though, seeing the users it attracted :)

Comment: @BPL I haven't down-voted, but I _did_ advise the OP to include some sample data that illustrates the problem. I guess I should also have told him that he needs to clearly explain that the code runs but that the decrypted data doesn't match the original data...

Comment: @PM2Ring Now I write a function of generate keys and encrypt separately. So how can I convert every 128 bytes exactly integer and back

Comment: You can't "convert every 128 bytes exactly integer and back" unless `m < n`.

Comment: @PM2Ring so when i read 120 bytes and n = 128bytes?

Comment: RSA is not ment for bulk encryption and thus libraries don't have support for encrypting messages bigger than what the key length allows. Use a symmetric algorithm designed for bulk encryption like AES. If you actually need the two key from RSA you can obtain this with [Hybrid Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

Comment: The issue with the question is that little to no research was done into encryption and this is evident based of the choice to use RSA for encryption data of substantial size.

Answer (score 2):

RSA is not meant for encrypting large amount of bytes. This is because, first of all, it is very ineffective as it requires a lot of overhead. You would indeed normally use a hybrid cryptosystem to avoid this problem.

Raw RSA as you are currently using is insecure. But that is not what is causing the issue. The problem as already stated is that the message is larger than N, the modulus. N is a number encoded in 128 bytes. But as it still cannot encrypt all messages of that size; if M is larger than N when interpreted as a big endian unsigned number then decryption will fail.

For example, an unsigned byte with value `1000 1001` is larger than `1000 0001` but both values will fit into 8 bits. So a message with that value cannot be encrypted with a key with a modulus with the second value.